# I've been told this is a balance the torques problem but I am not sure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

I have (what I have been told) balanced the torques problem which isn't something I have done in school yet (this is a personal project) so I need some help. The following image is a piece I am making in cad.

[image]

The black and white dot is the center of gravity. I want to know how much weight I would need to push down on the indicated area (orange arrow) to get it to rotate about the left-most bottom edge (indicated in blue). All the dimensions (mm) are in green. The total mass is 2071 grams. If you need any more info let me know. The center of mass can be moved to a certain extent if I do need to move it let me know where it should be and I can see what I can do. The kind of weight I want to be there is like a bit more than say the heaviest typist you know.